# MySQL: Combine a subselect and array into one IN statment

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I'm not sure if this is possible but what I like to do is the following:

- I have a list of id's stored in a table
- I have a list of numbers I have already

I want 1 in statement that joins the 2 eg,

```
SELCET * from `table1` where `ID` IN  ( (SELECT `id` from `table2` where `columnA` = 'yes') or (1,2,3,4))
```

but I am not sure how I can combine the two results in one statement.

Comment: O.T: Do you really have a 'yes' value in a column? just curious....

Comment: no, its a 1 or 0 in reality

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to have two separate `in` conditions:

```
SELCET *
FROM   `table1`
WHERE  `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `table2` WHERE `columnA` = 'yes') OR
       `id` IN (1,2,3,4)
```